# Can I call an Action<T> stored as delegate

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, casting, delegates

I am storing Action as Delegate. Also I have the T stored as an Interface.

Is there any way later on I can call the Action and pass the object?

```
public class MyAction {
    public IMyObject IMyObject { get; set; }
    public Delegate myDelegate { get; set; }
    public Type IMyObjectType { get; set; }
}
```

Where IMyObject is an empty interface

```
public interface IMyObject { }
```

I create MyAction instance from Action callback

```
public static MyAction Factory<T>(Action<T> callback) {
            return new MyAction() {
                myDelegate = callback, IMyObjectType = typeof (T)
            };
        }
```

Is is possible to call the delegate and pass IMyObject?

Later On I set the IMyObject before trying to call the Delegate(Action)

Answer (score 2):

**Make MyAction  generic as well**

```
class MyAction<T> where T : IMyObject
{
   public T IMyObject { get; set; }
   public Action<T> action { get; set; }
   public Type IMyObjectType { get { return typeof(T); }
}
```

The problem is that you can't create the MyAction without know the type of the argument at compile time, unless you create it using reflection (which may be useful if you call the action multiple times and want to optimize execution).

**Call the action using `DynamicInvoke`**
(which is using reflection and is very slow).

You could also consider making it a `Action` which includes the arguments. It depends on your requirements.

```
myDelegate = () => callback(argument);
```

Comment: Define very slow please. When is this a problem? Will it lag your UI or will it only be a problem on thousands of iterations?

Comment: @Gusdor performance is relative; to know whether this is a problem *for you*, you should look at the performance *in your scenario*. The caution of it being slow is very valid.

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell this is the explaintaion i was hoping to prompt from Stefan. 'X is slow, avoid avoid' is an answer that really grinds my gears, particularly when there is no other way to meet the OP requirements.

Comment: I remember a post from one of those C# Gurus who said that it is around 170 times slower than a normal invoke.

Answer (score 2):

If the type isn't fixed (as in: it is just `Delegate`, and you can't know the `T`), then you can use:

```
action.myDelegate.DynamicInvoke(args);
```

but that is relatively slow. If you are doing this lots, you would want to avoid that. Frankly, it would be more efficient to just use an `Action<object>` (or similar) throughout, and cast *inside the callback* - then your code would know the delegate type and could use regular invoke.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` to invoke an untyped `Delegate`.